# Server specific Web.config replacement

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010. I want to set up a different connection string for my "Testing" Configuration. I have tried doing it by using config transformations, but it does not seem to work.

In my **Web.config** my connection string is the following:

```
<add name="MyDb" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DevelopmentDb;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I found out that you can replace the connection string defined in Web.config by adding config transformation. I right clicked on Web.config and clicked on "Add config transformations". This created a ***Web.TEST.config*** file. I then added a connection string replacement, but it doesnt seem to work. It still uses the connection string defined in **Web.config**.

The file contents of **Web.TEST.config** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".
  -->

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDb" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas to what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Transformations get applied when you *deploy* the project, not when you compile it.

If you are using IIS, you can deploy to the configured web application directory, which will cause the transform to apply.