# Is there a way to retrieve user specific information when running a cloud project locally?

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, tokenize

We have a few values which are user specific in our cscfg files like service bus namespaces, usernames and passwords etc. I wonder if we can retrieve those values upon build time when running the solution locally so the scenario would be:

1. Get solution from repo
2. Build locally (this will cause developer specific variables to replace either tokens like %username% or %password% or pre-defined values in config files
3. Run solution without having to substitute anything in config files

I have seen this solution implemented with powershell, but I am looking to an alternative to that. Basically you run a ps script before building the solution and that replaces (de-tokenizes) any tokens in config files.
I wonder if I can do that with web.config transformation at all. But then again I suppose need to change values in the cscfg. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just came across this which answers to one question about web.config transforms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244632/server-specific-web-config-replacement

Comment: The Azure Package command will run the web.config transforms during packaging. We use this to setup web.config end points in the local emulator vs. cloud deployment config